# primefaces - Draggable from <p:dataTable> works but not visible

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, draggable

I am implementing a drag-drop feature for a list of images which are displayed in a `<p:dataTable>`. The feature works fine and the ajax calls are being made too.

Only issue is when the image is dragged from the dataTable, it doesn't show the image being dragged over other html components...i.e. it hides behind other html components. I tried the `overflow:visible` too for my dataTable and other components, but no luck yet.

I even removed the layouts I had in my page. Still no luck. Has this anything to do with `<p:dataTable>` ?

Using primefaces 3.3.1

**The jsf page code :**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title>Img</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>




    <h:form>

        <p:scrollPanel>
            <p:layout fullPage="true" >

                <p:layoutUnit position="north" minSize="100">

                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" maxSize="200" minSize="200">

                    <p:dataTable var="img"
                                 value="#{orderBean.userMedia.mediaList}"
                                 id="dataTableID">
                        <p:column>

                            <p:graphicImage id="imgID" value="#{img.thumbNail.getString('url')}"/>
                            <p:draggable for="imgID" revert="true"/>

                        </p:column>



                    </p:dataTable>

                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">

                    <p:outputPanel >

                        <p:panel id="outputPanelID" style="background: red; width: 100%;height: 100%">

                        </p:panel>

                        <p:droppable for="outputPanelID">
                            <p:ajax listener="#{orderBean.onDropImage}"/>
                        </p:droppable> 

                    </p:outputPanel>

                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" minSize="60">

                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>
        </p:scrollPanel>


    </h:form>  

</h:body>
```

As you can see in the screenshot. The image is being dragged and the backend listener is also being called but the image being dragged goes below other html components.
Don't know what I am missing.

**Thanks.**

The screenshot :
[image: Drag happens but below the other html components]

Comment: can you post the codes and outputs ?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited and added the jsf code and a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which works for me.
The trick is to manipulate the z-index in the center layout unit during dragging.

The following code achieves this:

```
// Enable visibility for drag-and-drop items in Primefaces layout container <p:layoutUnit position="center">
$(".ra-page-pool-items-panel .ui-draggable").draggable({
    start: function() {
        $(".ui-layout-pane-center").each(function(){
            my.centerZIndex = $(this).css("z-index");
            $(this).css({"z-index": 0});
        });
    },

    stop: function() {
        $(".ui-layout-pane-center").each(function(){
            $(this).css({"z-index": my.centerZIndex});
        });
    }
});
```

So here is all together:
The jsf (hint: hfx:pageItem is a private component):

```
<h:form id="f">
<p:layout>
    <p:layoutUnit id="west" position="west" size="200" header="PAGE POOL" resizable="true" collapsible="true">
        <t:div styleClass="ra-page-pool-items-panel">
            <t:dataList id="dl" var="ppp" value="#{bean.pagePoolPages}">
                <hfx:pageItem id="ppp" model="#{ppp}" />
                <p:draggable for="ppp" revert="true" zindex="10" />
            </t:dataList>
        </t:div>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center" header="PAGE LIST">
        <t:div id="itemsPanel" styleClass="ra-page-list-items-panel">
            <t:dataList id="dl" var="plp" value="#{bean.pageListPages}">
                <hfx:pageItem id="plp" model="#{plp}" />
                <p:draggable for="plp" revert="true" zindex="10" />
            </t:dataList>
        </t:div>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Further there is a Javascript WebUI initialization function WebUIUtils.initWebUI(), which is called on page init.

```
$(function(){WebUIUtils.initWebUI();});

var WebUIUtils = {
    centerZIndex: 0,

    initWebUI: function() {
        var my = this;

        // Enable visibility for drag-and-drop items in Primefaces layout container <p:layout>
        $(".ui-layout-unit .ui-layout-unit-content").each(function(){
            $(this).css({background: "red", overflow: "visible"});
        });


        // Enable visibility for drag-and-drop items in Primefaces layout container <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        $(".ra-page-pool-items-panel .ui-draggable").draggable({        // Do it only for the west items draggables
            start: function() {
                $(".ui-layout-pane-center").each(function(){
                    my.centerZIndex = $(this).css("z-index");
                    $(this).css({"z-index": 0});
                });
            },

            stop: function() {
                $(".ui-layout-pane-center").each(function(){
                    $(this).css({"z-index": my.centerZIndex});
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Manfred. I haven't tried your solution, as the requirement was urgent. Have given an alternative solution. In the next release it will be drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `z-index` on `<p:draggable>`?

For example, try to set `zindex="10000"` to have a high `z-index`. And if that works, you can try 1000 or 100.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem.

I also have a `p:layout` container with two layout units, `west` and `center`. I have images in both containers and want to drag and drop them between both containers.

Now I found out how to make the draggables in the center visible outside its container.
  You have to set overflow to visible on the layout unit content with

```
$(".ui-layout-unit .ui-layout-unit-content ")
.each(function(){
    $(this).css({overflow: "visible"});
});
```

to make them visible.

But this approach does only fit for the `center` container and not for the `west` container. I try to find out how to make the `west` draggables also visble in `center` container.

Maybe this information helps at the moment.